Server Component data fetching does not work in production
Used fetch function in server Component it's work perfect in development but when deploy to vercel or netlify it does not fetch the data.
I even try to revalidate:0 and cache: no-store so it does not fetch at build time, I also check my env base URL it's perfect, in postmen same URL giving response as expected
async function getItems() {
  const header = headers();
  try {
    const res = await fetch(
      `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_DOMAIN!}api/Fees/Status`,
      {
        method: "GET",
        headers: header,
      }
    );
    const data = await res.json();
    console.log(data);
    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}

export default async function Page() {
  let data = await getItems();
  var dayscount =
    countDaysFromGivenDateToCurrent(data?.FeesRecord.feesPaidupto) || 0;

Return feesrecord in development but when I tried in production I do not received any data.

Is there any error or what ?

check  vercel logs. and double check if the NEXT_PUBLIC_DOMAIN variable is defined in Vercel

Actually there is no error but data is not populated through component (I think res does not receive data ) , I read somewhere this might be due to cached data at build time use revalidate or cache : no store but both the way does not work in my case ,

this is gonna sound weird but, i had the same problem from prior , the server component didnt fetch the data properly or didnt fetch anything at all , the solution on my end until now is to convert it to a client component i tried to dismantle it and move a large chunk of my code to components and the route.ts file so it wont be as heavy on the client.

Have you resolved this issue? I am getting the same
